# Firebase retrieving data not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to achieve a private chatroom in my Rails application with Firebase.
But now I feel confused why the following code can't work. I am new in Firebase, so I basically don't know how to solve these bugs.

First, I want to retrieve data from my firebase database. As you can see, I already create two records in firebase.

[image]

Here is my code, I want it to be pure javascript instead of `node.js`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  $(function() {
    var config = {
      apiKey: "MyKey",
      authDomain: "MyDomain",
      databaseURL: "https://example.com",
      projectId: "MyProjectId",
      storageBucket: "MystorageBucket",
      messagingSenderId: "592744784916"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    loadMessages();

    function loadMessages() {
      // Loads the last 12 messages and listen for new ones.
      var callback = function(snap) {
        var data = snap.val();
        console.log(data);
      };
      firebase.database().ref('/messages/').limitToLast(12).on('child_added', callback);
      firebase.database().ref('/messages/').limitToLast(12).on('child_changed', callback);
    }
  });
</script>
```

However, when I open developer console, I didn't see any message in the console.

Or there are better solution combine Rails with Firebase will also be a great answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database you show in your screenshot is Cloud Firestore. The database that you access in your code is the Realtime Database. While both are part of Firebase, they are completely separate databases, each with their own API.

To access Cloud Firestore from your code, read its documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/

Comment: Thanks, it saves my day, I was stuck and have no idea what's going on.